# jquery - find the character in the string and wrap the remaining character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a heading like:

```
foobar|foo
```

How do I search for the character '|', then wrap it in span along with the remaining character in the right?

The result should be:

```
foobar< span>|foo< /span>.
```

In the website we have different length headings like:

```
hello|my mario
you are the best|my friend
```

So i want to detect the '|' character and wrap it with the remaining.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Comment: `console.log(  'foobar|foo'.replace(/\|[^]*$/, ' <span>$&</span>')  );`

Comment: thanks @Guedes .. this is helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inspired by @guedes answer

try this:

```
var headingText = $('h2').text();
var newText = ( headingText.replace(/\|[^]*$/, ' <span>$&</span>') );
$('h2.heading').html(newText)


html
<h2 class="heading">foobar|foo</h2>
```

you can have any heading you like.e.g

bar|foo

doodle|lorem.

Answer (score 0):

Guedes answer is certainly less code - but another way could be:

```
var val = 'foobar|foo';

var before = val.substr(0, val.indexOf('|'));
var after = val.substr(val.indexOf("|") + 1); 

$('.result').empty().append( before +'<span>|' + after + '</span>');
```

Here's a fiddle you can test with: [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jamiesmith/9cee4qju/)